# Simulated annealing of small protein

Tags: molecular-dynamics, proteins

I understand the general concept of simulated annealing and have seen various criteria in papers, but I was wondering if there is a general rule of thumb for selecting a final structure, how many replicates one has to do, equilibration time (I’ve seen that it’s generally a few picoseconds) and selecting a max temperature when there isn’t an experimental melting curve. I used alpha fold to predict the structure of a small protein and want to do simulated annealing before starting extensive MD simulations - I could really use some general guidance on establishing a protocol.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Sorry for taking so long to welcome you! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you, although your absence for the last 6 months might mean that we took too long to help you with this question. If you do come back and see this, feel free to leave a comment to show us that you're back, and we can reopen the question too!